# Why does jupyter (local) and google colab return different results for deterministic algorithm and same input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I have a superpixel mask and want to get those superpixel patches which are on the boundary of the mask. I get different results for the same input and algorithm whether I run it locally or on Colab. The result I get on Colab is the correct one.

Local pytorch: 1.12.1
Colab pytorch: 1.12.1+cu113

Here you can see an image of one mask:
[image]

Here you can find the corresponding tensor if you want to reproduce the result:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tHPIak21-a_ksjn6RhVjObXcTXuiiDRn?usp=sharing

Here is the algorithm:

```
import torch
torch.use_deterministic_algorithms(True)
torch.manual_seed(42)

test = torch.load(SUPERPIXEL_EXAMPLE)
def flatten(L):
    for item in L:
        try:
            yield from flatten(item)
        except TypeError:
            yield item

def get_outer_values(superpixel_mask, flatten_list_fct=flatten):
    superpixel_mask_refined = superpixel_mask.clone()
    outer_superpixel_rows, outer_superpixel_cols, outer_all = [], [], []
    tuples = torch.nonzero(superpixel_mask_refined)
    rows = torch.unique(tuples[:,0])
    columns = torch.unique(tuples[:,1])
    # scan over rows 
    for i in rows:
        current_row = superpixel_mask_refined[i, :]
        unique_non_zeroed_row = torch.unique(current_row[current_row.nonzero(as_tuple=True)], sorted=False)
        first_superpixel = unique_non_zeroed_row[-1]
        last_superpixel = unique_non_zeroed_row[0]
        outer_superpixel_rows.append(first_superpixel.item())
        outer_superpixel_rows.append(last_superpixel.item())
    print(f"Outer sp rows {torch.unique(torch.Tensor(outer_superpixel_rows))}")
    # scan over columns
    for i in columns:
        current_column = superpixel_mask_refined[:, i]
        unique_non_zeroed_column = torch.unique(current_column[current_column.nonzero(as_tuple=True)], sorted=False)
        first_superpixel = unique_non_zeroed_column[-1]
        last_superpixel = unique_non_zeroed_column[0]
        outer_superpixel_cols.append(first_superpixel.item())
        outer_superpixel_cols.append(last_superpixel.item())
    print(f"Outer sp cols {torch.unique(torch.Tensor(outer_superpixel_cols))}")
    outer_all.append(outer_superpixel_cols)
    outer_all.append(outer_superpixel_rows)
    outer_all = flatten(outer_all)
    result = list(set(outer_all))
    result.sort()
    print(f"All outer values are: {result}")
get_outer_values(test)
```

This is the output on Colab:

```
Outer sp rows tensor([102., 113., 119., 120., 124., 140., 145., 158., 159., 163., 182., 201.,
        212., 218., 229., 232., 236., 244., 248., 259., 261., 262.])
Outer sp cols tensor([102., 112., 113., 118., 119., 120., 121., 122., 124., 132., 145., 159.,
        212., 232., 236., 259., 261., 262., 263., 264.])
All outer values are: [102, 112, 113, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 124, 132, 140, 145, 158, 159, 163, 182, 201, 212, 218, 229, 232, 236, 244, 248, 259, 261, 262, 263, 264]
```

And this is the result for the same input and algorithm when run locally:

```
Outer sp rows tensor([102., 112., 113., 118., 119., 120., 124., 126., 135., 140., 145., 157.,
        158., 159., 160., 163., 177., 182., 193., 198., 199., 201., 212., 218.,
        219., 226., 229., 232., 234., 236., 244., 247., 248., 259., 261., 262.,
        263.])
Outer sp cols tensor([102., 112., 113., 118., 119., 120., 121., 122., 124., 126., 132., 138.,
        140., 142., 145., 153., 157., 159., 160., 166., 178., 181., 182., 199.,
        201., 202., 207., 212., 219., 226., 232., 233., 235., 236., 247., 248.,
        249., 251., 261., 262., 263., 264.])
All outer values are: [102, 112, 113, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 124, 126, 132, 135, 138, 140, 142, 145, 153, 157, 158, 159, 160, 163, 166, 177, 178, 181, 182, 193, 198, 199, 201, 202, 207, 212, 218, 219, 226, 229, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 244, 247, 248, 249, 251, 259, 261, 262, 263, 264]
```

These are the problematic superpixels which are different between both runs:

```
[135, 138, 142, 153, 157, 160, 166, 177, 178, 181, 193, 198, 199, 202, 207, 219, 226, 233, 234, 235, 247, 249, 251, 126]
```

I am really puzzled and boiled down the issue to this function but I can't see why they return different results. Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is related to the random seed of PyTorch. After importing the torch, you can try to give the seed, such as

```py
torch.manual_seed(x)
```

You can set x as any positive integer that you want.

Also, it would be best if you tried to set the deterministic by using

```py
torch.use_deterministic_algorithms(True)
```

Comment: Hello @amisotcm Thank you so much for taking the time to look into this. I tried it with your option but unfortunately the result is the same. Could you maybe try it on your side? I would be immensely happy about it. 

I also added your snippet to my code above now.

Comment: Also, do you have any idea why someone gave -1? Is something missing or is my question not clear? Sorry to ask but I am no expert here.